# Как добавить анимации 2D персонажу в UE4?

Tags: анимация, 2d, unreal-engine-4

У меня есть заготовленные спрайты под анимацию
[image: конкретно спрайты*]

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы во время движения моего персонажа влево , воспроизводился flipbook left (на картинке подписано), когда идет движение на право, воспроизводился flipbook right и так далее
Но главная проблема заключается в том, что этот Character является Enemy, то есть игрок им не играет, он будет в роли искусственного интеллекта (он будет перемещаться самостоятельно)

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, есть огромное количество статей на разных сайтах и роликах на ютубе, где разбирается данная механика. Сейчас точно по действиям описать не смогу, но в целом логику построить попытаюсь. Вдруг на данном этапе это поможет. Тебе нужно зайти в Enemy и прописать в его блупринте такую закономерность: Если скорость меньше 0, то поставить в анимацию нужный флипбук, если больше 0, то другой, если равна 0, то оставить idle. Могу напутать с больше/меньше, но там секундное дело подставить и проверить. Это решение будет работать если: Enemy умеет только ходить (при беге можно еще поколдовать со скоростью) и УЖЕ умеет ходить. С искреннем желанием помочь прикреплю ссылку на статью habr с решением твоей проблемы (https://habr.com/ru/post/237409/). К слову, если анимация движения в разные стороны зеркальна, то можно оставить одну и отражать её каждый раз при смене знака в скорости движения (в одну сторону она идет в +, в другую в -). Надеюсь, что помог. Если это не решит твою проблему и чуть позже не появится ответа с пошаговым решением и скринами, то тыкни меня через неделью. Расскажу на примере.